# How to grant access to tables without specific prefix in postgres to a user?

Tags: postgresql

I have a database named something. I want to create a user and get access to all tables in this database except the tables with a specific prefix.
Imagine this is my database with the below tables:

```
users
cards
directus_roles
directus_files
directus_users
```

I want to have a user in my Postgres who can't access those tables with the `directus` prefix.

Comment: You mean other than brute force permissions, I'm guessing?  Can you not put the directus tables into their own schema?  It will simplify maintenance.

Comment: Great...  and that way you can do things like this:  `grant all on all tables in schema <whatever> to john, chris, bob;`  With the tables you don't want being in a separate schema, that keeps it clean.